# How to search data stored in tuples using Salat?

Tags: mongodb, scala, salat

```
case class Venue(@Key("_id") id: Int, 
                 location: Tuple2[Double, Double],
                 name: String)

object VenueDAO extends SalatDAO[Venue, Int](collection = MongoConnection()("ec")("venue"))

VenueDAO.find(?) //return Option[Venue]
```

How to search data by location using Salat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to start out:

1. Per the [README.txt](https://github.com/novus/salat/blob/48c001b37bd37e6c2f42df72ecbedb0bd0ef4aec/README.md), Salat doesn't support Tuples.
2. Perhaps you are thinking of Mongo's [Geospatial coordinate support](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-geospatial/)?

In any case, since Salat doesn't support Tuples, here is what you can do:

```
case class Location(x: Double, y: Double)

case class Venue(@Key("_id") id: Int, location: Location, name, String)

val venue = Venue(1, Location(1.0, 1.0), "NYC")
VenueDAO.save(venue)   
println(s"Saved: $venue")
val found = VenueDAO.findOne(MongoDBObject("location.x" -> 1.0, "location.y" -> 1.0))
println(s"Found: $found")
```

Prints:

```
Saved: Venue(1,Location(1.0,1.0),NYC)
Found: Some(Venue(1,Location(1.0,1.0),NYC))
```

Comment: ...by clicking the Checkbox next to the answer?